# How long is the picture url from FB Open Graph User Object valid?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have a Facebook application, I have included the Facebook Javascript SDK and it works quite good.

I am asking the user for basic permissions, I want my application to query after the picture object on the users profile.

This is my code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

        FB.api('/me/picture?type=square', function(response) {
            if( !response.data.is_silhouette ){
                var url = response.data.url; // For how long will this data exist?
                console.log('You have an avatar on your profile!');

            }else{
                console.log('You have no avatar uploaded to your profile!');
            }
        });

    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
});
```

It retrieves the profiles avatar image.
But for how long is the url to my picture valid? I expect the URL is only temporary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this image will be valid forever, or at least until the user decides to delete it. After all it´s a static url.

BUT: if you want it to stay up-to-date with the actual user picture, you can always use the graph url of the user:

> http://graph.facebook.com/[user-id]/picture?type=square

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so if I add on parameters like width and height. It's still a static url?

Comment: i´d say so, yes. after all you always get a static one, i´d assume that it gets generated the first time you use a specific width/height.